# How to store urls for making ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a javascript file which makes many ajax calls to my server using the code similar to the one below:

```
var url = "/api/read";
$.ajax({
type : 'GET',
url :  url,
async : false,
success : function(data) {
  }
});
```

Is there any way to store all the urls somewhere so that I dont need to have hard-coded urls in my javascript files? Something like, I have a reference to some file/anything which gives me access to all urls I can use to make ajax calls?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can store such list in a separate file. But you have to do extra AJAX request to load the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You could store all your urls in a seperate javascript file and use it as constants.

If you dont want an javascript you can also use json instead.

Comment: If I have a xyz.json file having                                                                                                {
    "readData" : "/api/read"
}                                                                                                              How do I refer and read this in my javascript file to fetch the readData url?

Comment: Request the server with an ajax get and store the json in a variable. You should do this only once not every time you need an url. Then you can access your urls by `myUrls.readData`

Comment: I did make a GET ajax request to load my .json file. console.log(data) gives me my json file content properly. but I am not able to read a key value pair from the data. Here is my code:                                          success : function(data) {
 urls = data;
        console.log(data);
      console.log(urls.key);
    },
console.log(data) o/p is {"key":"value"}

Comment: This worked for me: `$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: urlToJson,
    success: function (json) {
      var urls = json;
      console.log(urls.geturl);
    }
  });`

Comment: Thanks! This worked! urls variable is accesible on entire javascript page? I  mean can I simply do a GET request to this json file once(on page load) and read the key values in any other function of the java script file?

Comment: How can I make this accessible on my entire javascript page?

Comment: Ok I got it. I made the urls variable global.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create a global variable

```
  var url = {
    read:"/api/read",
    write:"/api/write/",
    more:"/api/more/"
   }

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url.read,
  /* this gives the first url - "/api/read" */
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `localStorage` if you want to store some data and a good thing is that, that data could be used even after refreshing the page but the bad thing (may be, depending upon the requirements) is that, that data is stored in browser so if you have saved urls in chrome then you can't access them from firefox.

however if you want your data to be deleted when your page's tab is removed or the browser is closed then you can use `sessionStorage` but again it is stored in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript array to store all your url's. Access them based on the index like this.

```
var url = ["/api/read", "/api/write/", "/api/more/"]

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url[0],
  /* this gives the first url - "/api/read" */
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript object as follows:

```
var urls = {
    "readData" : "/api/read",
    "writeData" : "/api/write",
    "urlName" : "/api/update"
};
```

and use it as:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: urls.writeData,
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: look at the answer before you post